# Should the noun after "any" be singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, determiners

I always thought with "any" I should use the plural, but on the internet I can find both:

- It can be found in **any book**.
- It can be found in **any books**
- Do you have **any books?**
- It can be said in **any language**.
- This can be understood by **anyone**.
- It has been used in **any form**.

So, what's correct? 
Is there any rule?

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t have any idea what you are asking.

Comment: I think what the OP is asking is: when do you use the plural with *any* and when do you use the singular? We say *"any hardware store will sell you one"*, and not **"any hardware stores will sell you one"*. But we also say *"are any hardware stores open on Sunday?"* and not **"is any hardware store open on Sunday?"*

Comment: To forestall comments, *"is any hardware store open on Sunday?"* is perfectly fine as a rhetorical question, but I would use *"are any hardware stores ..."* if I was asking where to buy some tool. Looking at these examples, I am fairly sure that I can tell whether to use the plural and singular for any specific sentence, but I have no idea how to codify this as a rule.

Comment: @PeterShor I believe tchrist was being ironic!

Comment: tchrist? ironic? never!

Comment: There's two kinds of _any_ -- [Negative Polarity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) _any_, which requires a negative context (of which questions are one), and is  the _any_ in _Do you have any books?_ -- and [Possible Polarity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) _any_, which requires a possibility modal, and is the _any_ in all the other sentences. They behave differently; Neg _any_ can alternate with _some_ in affirmative contexts, but Modal _any_ is effectively equivalent to _all_, for instance. Oh, and the last sentence is ungrammatical -- no neg, no modal.

Comment: In addition to the _any's_ as used in the sentences above, there is also the 'free-choice'(CGEL) _any_, as in: _You can have any book you want_. In other words, you can choose, but you can only have one.

Answer (score 8):

Before you can choose whether to use a singular or plural noun with *any*, you need to know which of the various functions and meanings it has in the context in which you are using it. In each of your affirmative sentences *any* is equivalent to *every*.

> It can be found in any / every book.
>
> This can be understood by anyone / everyone.
>
> It can be said in any / every language.

For this reason, the following does not work:

> ? It can be found in any / every books.

In the interrogative sentences *any* does not mean *every*. In fact it does not really have a meaning at all and could be omitted:

> Do you have books?
>
> Is there a rule?

As to whether the singular or plural should be used with uncount nouns, the plural is more common:

> Do you have any children? - ? Do you have any child?
>
> Do you have any books? - ? Do you have any book?

But if you are expecting there to be only one of the thing in question, the singular may be used. In other words:

> Is there any rule?

may be said in expectation that there will be only one rule.

Comment: In the penultimate section, you state "the plural is more common" (with which I agree), but then illustrate it by using the singular in your examples, which I find confusing. And what is the "?" at the front of the line meant to indicate?

Comment: @TrevorD. Thanks. Edited to include the more common examples. The question mark at the beginning of a sentence is a convention to show that the sentence is questionable! An asterisk in the same place denotes an error.

Comment: Thanks. When you mention use of the "?" as "a convention", do you mean *a convention on SE* or what? It's (obviously) not a convention I've ever come across.  As regards the actual answer, to me, *Do you have any child/book?* seems plainly **wrong** - not merely questionable. I would say *Do you have **a** child/book?* if I were using the singular.

Comment: A question mark at the beginning of sentence is the convention used in _The Cambridge Grammar Of The Language_ to indicate constructions 'of questionable grammaticality'. I'm not sure about _Do you have any book?_ It doesn't fall into the same category as what the CGEL denotes *ungrammatical. Their example is, coincidently, _*This books is mine_.

Comment: @ Shoe: As usual, context is everything! I doubt many people would seriously object to, for example, *"Do you have any book that might shed some light on this question?"*. The speaker probably expects there will be *no* such books, and at best he's only expecting there might be *one*, so asking for plural *books* could seem a bit "presumptuous".

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Agreed. Context is king!  _Do you have any book?_ is at least of dubious grammaticality when asked in order to determine if someone possesses books. But it is perfectly ok when followed by your qualifying clause and asked in the expectation that there might be at most one such.

Answer (score 3):

Italian speakers are often confused by the different *uses* of "any" *and*  its different *meanings*.

[**Any**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/any) is usually defined as being an adjective, an adverb, a pronoun, a determiner and until today I was unaware of a further subclass: a [numeral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_%28linguistics%29)

> Many words of different parts of speech indicate number or quantity.
>   Quantifiers do not enumerate, or designate a specific number, but give
>   another, **often less specific, indication of amount**. Examples are words
>   such as every, most, least, some, etc.

Hence, "any" has a similar meaning to "a" and is *normally* used with *uncountable* and *plural nouns.*

1. (a) Do you have any books? (plural noun)
   (b) I haven't got any books.
2. (a) Do you have a book? (singular noun)
   (b) I haven't got a book
3. (a) Do you need any information? (uncountable noun)
   (b) I haven't got any information.
4. (a) *Do you need a information?  NO
   (b) *I haven't got a information. NO

Examples and explanations taken (and adapted) from *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan:
**"Any" meanings and uses**

1. It doesn't matter which

   - It's my treat. Choose *any* dress you like. [*Choose a/one dress*]
   - Take *any* card.  [*Take a/one card*]
   - *Any* book on grammar will tell you how to use "any". [*Any one book = every book on grammar*]
2. In questions and negative sentences "any" can be used with comparatives, with "different" and in the expressions *any/good*, *any/use*, and *any/point*.

   - Is she any better?
   - I can't walk any further
   - You don't look any different now than ten years ago.
   - Is there any point in carrying on?
   - Was the film any good?
3. In sentences with negative adverbs such as *never*, *hardly* and *rarely*

   - He never has any spare time
   - She hardly eats anything
   - They rarely visit anyone

---

As a result the OP's phrases:

> It can be found in any book
>   It can be said in any language
>     This can be understood by anyone (i.e. any person)

mean it doesn't matter which book/language/person, because *every* book/language/person has this quality or ability.

Comment: If you use an indefinite article with "information" (which of course you shouldn't do at all), you should use "an information".