# "any product group" or "any product groups"?

Tags: grammatical-number, multiplicity

I can't decide, both sounds right and return results on Google.

**So is it "any product group" or "any product groups"?**

Context: The context is that some product can has sub-product that are part of groups, some have products and some don't. So I will add a method to know "any_product_groups?", "has_product_groups?", "any_product_group?", ... I'm not sure.

**Example**: "Has this product any product group(s)?"

Comment: As example sentence would go a long way to helping understand what you're asking.  Also, "can haz"? :)

Comment: ok, I added an example

Comment: possible duplicate of [*"Any" followed by singular or plural countable nouns?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112996/any-followed-by-singular-or-plural-countable-nouns) Also [*The use of any with plural/singular words*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116742/) and doubtless others.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming methods in a computer program

Comment: Hmmm, yes, but I try to make my methods names correct in english (naming methods in CS is a subset of using english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct sentence would be:

"Does this product have any product groups?"

*Any* would always be followed the plural (or mass noun).  You could also say "Does this product have *a* product group?"

However, "product group" is a weird phrase that doesn't mean what I think you want it to mean.  I would say that a product group is a group of products, so for a product to have a product group, as opposed to *belong* to a product group, seems awkward.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it's a little awkward but product have child product groups