# When is any/anyone singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Are these the correct constructions?

1. Do any of the students write well?
2. Does anyone write well?

Comment: There are two questions here. (1) Possible duplicate of [The use of any with plural/singular words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116742/the-use-of-any-with-plural-singular-words) // (2) is answered by nohat at [anyone {followed by} they ... why ...?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/anyone-they-or-he-she-why-is-it-sometimes-plural).

Comment: In these sentences, _do_ agrees with the subject noun phrase, which is between it and _write_. The subject noun phrase in (1) is _any of the students_, and in (2) is _anyone_. _Anyone_ is obviously singular, so it gets _does_; but _any of the students_ means '1 or more of the students', which is plural, so it gets _do_. NPIs like _any_ often appear in questions, and when they do, they can cause problems in agreement.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: 2 is **not** answered by the linked post by nohat. Verb agreement and the use of "singular they" are two separate things: we can refer back to an indefinite singular noun phrase like "a student" with "singular they" (example: "If any student forgets the homework assignment, they can check it online") but we can't use plural verb agreement for the verb after "any student" (*"If any student forget the homework assignment, they can check it online").